# How to Create a Predicate object and pass it manually in code to the Spring CrudRepository

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data

I have a method that should perform persist action on an object that is in from the RestController, but before that it should make sure that the Object name is unique , so I am trying to use the .exists(Predicate predicate) method in the spring CrudRepository class.

but I don't know how to create this Predicate Object, which is usually passed from the request url to the JPA directly, I need to know what is the syntax of creating a Predicate in the code.

This is my restController

```
@RestController("MyObjectRestController")
@RequestMapping(value = "/v1.0/myObject", produces = "application/json")
public class MyObjectRestController extends BaseRestController<MyObject> {

    @Autowired
    private MyObjectService service;

public ResponseEntity<?> save(@RequestBody MyObject body)
            throws NotFoundException {
            return service.saveNew(body);
    }
}
```

and this is the MyObjectService Class where I want to use the exists(Preidicate) before the calling the save method.

```
@Service
public class MyObjectService extends BaseService<MyObject> {
    @Autowired
    private MyObjectRepository repository;

public Long saveNew(MyObject work){
        if(repository.exists(predicateObject )) // here is my problem
            System.out.println("This name exists, can't save your object");
        return work.getId();
    }
}
```

My repository which is inherited from CrudRepository

```
@Repository
public interface MyObjectRepository extends BaseRepository<MyObject>  {

    public MyObject findByName(String name);

}
```

The BaseRepository

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseRepository<S extends BaseEntity> extends PagingAndSortingRepository<S, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<S>
{

}
```

Comment: What does your `MyObjectRepository` look like? the `exists` method should take the type of the class you have assigned as the ID of the `MyObject` class. As per: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html

Comment: If you're using querydsl integration, you should use the generated meta model, e.g. `QMyObject`, to create a `Predicate`.

Comment: You have failed to post the only relevant part of the code which is the definition of MyObjectRepository.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a predicate like this :

Predicate isDigit = c -> Character.isDigit( c );